# what disadvantages are there to use innerhtml to populate a div tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, innerhtml

what disadvantages are there to use inner HTML to populate a div tag
consider, all scenarios possible.
Thanku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One disadvantage is that you'll need to escape special characters manually. So, you'll need to encode characters like >, <, and & (see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_encoding) on HTML encoding).

This is pretty trivial to do since there are utilities to do this baked into the .NET libraries, like [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx), but many people will forget this and not test all the special cases.

Another downside, is that if you're just populating a `div` with some arbitrary HTML, that means you're probably building the HTML manually, which can go wrong if you're just using string concatenation or something primative like that.

If you're doing this client side, it's much better to just rely on appending elements to the DOM, rather than setting `innerHTML`.

Answer (score -1):

There's already a debate about this:
http://www.developer-x.com/content/innerhtml

Comment: This article is very outdated considering the heavy use of ajax/json these days.

Comment: @Jappie is right on - you're trying to use a document written in 2002 as a reference to a "debate" today? Some of those examples don't even work the same way now.